# VBA Loop macro across columns

Tags: vba, excel

Good Afternoon,

I have a worksheet that runs multiple macros.

module #1 lists the sub folders of a master directory across columns on row 3. (Works Correctly)

module #2 lists a specific sub folder from the resulting folder from module #1 based on keywords, the result is printed to row 4. This module functions correctly for column A, though I have been unsuccesful in repeating the calculation across the columns based on a reletive cell reference across row 3. What the code is doing is returning the correct result to A4, and then prints the same result to B4,C4... i cant seem to modify this code to consider the row 3 result for each column.

```
Private Sub PrintFolders()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim OBJFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object
Dim i As Integer

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A4:BZ4")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
Application.StatusBar = ""
'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set OBJFolder = objFSO.getfolder(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value)
i = i + 1

'loops through each folder in the directory and prints their names and path
On Error GoTo handleCancel

For Each objSubFolder In OBJFolder.SubFolders
If InStr(1, objSubFolder.Name, "Plans", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, objSubFolder.Name, "Sketches", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
Application.StatusBar = objSubFolder.Path & " " & objSubFolder.Name
    'print folder path
    Cells(1 + 3, i) = objSubFolder.Path
    i = i

Else
End If

Next objSubFolder
Next rCell
handleCancel:
If Err = 18 Then
 MsgBox "You cancelled"
End If

End Sub
```

any assistance is very appreciated.

Comment: `Set OBJFolder = objFSO.getfolder(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value)` is hardcoded to reference `A3` everytime. Is this what you want or do you want it to reference `B3 ... C3 ... D3 ... ` on each loop?

Comment: Indeed I would need the A3 reference to increment on each loop across row 3 I am unsure how to make the reference relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this, but I think using the Offset function will give you the cell relative to the current cell you are calculating from.

```
Private Sub PrintFolders()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim OBJFolder As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object
    Dim i As Integer

        Dim rCell As Range
        Dim rRng As Range

        Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A4:BZ4")

        For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Get the folder object
    Set OBJFolder = objFSO.getfolder(rCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value)
    i = i + 1

    'loops through each folder in the directory and prints their names and path
    On Error GoTo handleCancel

    For Each objSubFolder In OBJFolder.SubFolders
    If InStr(1, objSubFolder.Name, "Plans", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, objSubFolder.Name, "Sketches", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = objSubFolder.Path & " " & objSubFolder.Name
        'print folder path
        Cells(1 + 3, i) = objSubFolder.Path
        i = i
    Else

    End If

    Next objSubFolder
    Next rCell
    handleCancel:
    If Err = 18 Then
     MsgBox "You cancelled"
    End If

    End Sub
```